# I need an algorithm to walk a tree with optional and alternative nodes to calculate all possible paths

Tags: algorithm, tree-traversal

Given the following tree which is a sort of Backus-Nauf form like notation where
| indicates or (so B is F or G) and [] indicate optional (so H is optional)

```
Def: A B C
A: D E
B: F | G
C: [H] I
D: a b
E: c d
F: e f
G: g h
H: i j
I: k l

a: a
b: b
c: c
d: d
e: e
f: f
g: g
h: h
i: i
j: j
k: k
l: l
```

Which can be viewed as

```
              Def
    A          B          C
 D     E    F  |  G   [H]    I
a b   c d  e f   g h  i j   k l
```

I need to walk the tree extracting the leaf nodes and convert to the following tree which gives the possible routes

```
 Def
     a
         b
             c
                 d
                     e
                         f
                             i
                                 j
                                     k
                                         l
                             k
                                 l
                     g
                         h
                             i
                                 j
                                     k
                                         l
                             k
                                 l
```

So the possible paths are

abcdefijkl

abcdefkl

abcdghijkl

abcdghkl

I've a [repo](https://bitbucket.org/danthomas/pathfinder/src/master/) with a failing C# unit test (that sets up the tree and calls a basic recusive walker) that should hopefully clarify what I'm trying to achieve.

What I can't figure out is how to branch at optional and alternative nodes while maintaining the correct leaves to append subsequent leaves to.

Comment: Interesting question, but potential answerers will most likely not have the patience to dig through your repo. If you narrow down the error/issue and post the code in your question, you'll probably get more help.

Comment: thanks but there would would far too much code to post. repo is just this problem, one unit test so no digging required. just git clone and open in an editor.

Comment: This looks like a pretty standard depth-first tree traversal. What specific problem are you having? Also, asking us to clone your repo is excessive. Boil your problem down to something of manageable size and post it here. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: again, far too much code to post. a standard depth first traversal would visit each leaf once a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l. what i need it something that will branch at B (F or G) as that there are two alternate paths and again at C as H is optional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-recursive breadth-first search would probably look something along these lines (pseudo code). Kicked off by calling `findAllLeafPaths(Def)`:

```
var allPathsFound = {}
function findAllLeafPaths(startNode) {
    var tokenSequenceQueue = {
        createTokenSequenceFrom(startNode)
    }
    while (tokenSequenceQueue.isNotEmpty()) {
        var tokenSequence = tokenSequenceQueue.removeFirst()
        var allLeaves = true
        for (every token T in tokenSequence) {
            if isLeafNode(T)
                continue
            else if T's rule is "T: Y Z" {
                allLeaves = false
                tokenSequenceQueue.append(tokenSequence.replace(T, Y + Z))
            } else if T's rule is "T: [Y] Z" {
                allLeaves = false
                tokenSequenceQueue.append(tokenSequence.replace(T, Y + Z))
                tokenSequenceQueue.append(tokenSequence.replace(T, Z))
            } else if T's rule "T: Y | Z" {
                allLeaves = false
                tokenSequenceQueue.append(tokenSequence.replace(T, Y))
                tokenSequenceQueue.append(tokenSequence.replace(T, Z))
            }
        }
        if (allLeaves) {
            allPathsFound.add(tokenSequence)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is also a recursive depth-first version. I prefer the first one because the recursion puts your stack at the mercy of the max possible length of result paths:

```
var allPathsFound = {}
function toLeafNodes(tokenSequence) {
    var allLeaves = true
    for every token T in tokenSequence {
        if isLeafNode(T)
            continue
        else if T's rule is "T: Y Z" {
            allLeaves = false
            toLeafNodes(tokenSequence.replace(T, Y + Z)
        } else if T's rule is "T: [Y] Z" {
            allLeaves = false
            toLeafNode(tokenSequence.replace(T, Y + Z)
            toLeafNode(tokenSequence.replace(T, Z)
        } else if T's rule "T: Y | Z" {
            allLeaves = false
            toLeafNode(tokenSequence.replace(T, Y)
            toLeafNode(tokenSequence.replace(T, Z)
        }
    }
    if (allLeaves) {
        allPathsFound.add(tokenSequence)
    }
}
```

[Edit] The non-recursive version currently does one replace at a time and immediately puts the result sequence on the queue. It can be further optimized to do all possible replaces in one pass.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to build a tree from your definitions. Consider:

```
Def: A B C
A: D E
B: F | G
C: [H] I
```

Start with

```
A
 \
  B
   \
    C
```

Then replace A with D E:

```
D
 \
  E
   \
    B
     \
      C
```

Do the same thing with B (replace with F | G), and C (replace with [H] I), and you get:

```
      D
       \
        E     
    /       \
   F         G
  / \       / \
 I   H     I   H
      \         \
       I         I
```

Now, if you do a recursive depth-first traversal of that tree, you get the valid strings:

```
D E F I
D E F H I
D E G I
D E G H I
```

And you can replace D with "a b", etc. when you're outputting the strings.

I showed it step-by-step, but you can do it all in a single pass.